# Syntax Error line 0, col 349: Error: Expected Literal, got 'aS'

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, symfony, dql

I encountered a problem with my DQL requests, as the title suggests.

Here are my first lines, which don't seem to be the core of the bug :

```
$qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.localisation', 'loc')
        ->leftJoin('p.advert', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.accommodationStyle', 'aS')
        ->leftJoin('a.accommodationChoice', 'aC')
        ->where('loc.lat < :maxLat')
        ->setParameter('maxLat', $maxLat)
        ->andWhere('loc.lat > :minLat')
        ->setParameter('minLat', $minLat)
        ->andWhere('loc.lng < :maxLng')
        ->setParameter('maxLng', $maxLng)
        ->andWhere('loc.lng > :minLng')
        ->setParameter('minLng', $minLng)
    ;
```

The problem is here :

```
            $orX = $qb->expr()->orX();

            $orX->add('aS.name = :house') 
                ->add('aS.name = :flat')
                ->add('aS.name = :villa') 
                ->add('aS.name = :bungalow')
            ;

            $qb->andWhere($orX)
               ->setParameters(
                    array(
                        'house' => 'House',
                        'flat' => 'Flat',
                        'villa' => 'Villa',
                        'bungalow' => 'Bungalow'
                    )
                )
            ;
```

I provide shreds of my entities :

Advert contains these lines :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MR\PlatformBundle\Entity\AccommodationChoice", inversedBy="adverts", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $accommodationChoice;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MR\PlatformBundle\Entity\AccommodationStyle", inversedBy="adverts", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $accommodationStyle;
```

AccommodationStyle, this one :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MR\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert", mappedBy="accommodationStyle")
 */
private $adverts;
```

AccommodationChoice, this one :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MR\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert", mappedBy="accommodationChoice")
 */
private $adverts;
```

and Person, this other one :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MR\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="author", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $advert;
```

I explored the existing posts on the subject, but no one seemed to help for that case, thanks in advance for some help (would be much appreciated) !

Comment: I corrected villa into :villa, but that was just a mistake during my writing of that post

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `aS` as an alias, because it is a reserved word (`AS`). Just choose another one.

Comment: Wonderful, as simple as that. Thank you trincot. It's important to keep that in mind.